# How do I change my UK visa validity period?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-extensions, visa-expiration

I am from India. I applied for a UK visitor visa for a 6-week observership at a hospital in Glasgow. The visa is valid up to April 22nd. However, in my application, I had mentioned that I would be at the hospital until April 30th and would be sightseeing until May 15th. How do I go about ensuring that the validity date is changed to May 15th. Whom must I contact?

Comment: You should have received instructions on how to report an error in your visa. Please refer to them. If you didn't receive any such instructions, contact the consulate.

Comment: @MichaelHampton you should post this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

If the validity period covers the 6-week observership you documented in your visa application, then an ECO may have made a decision based on that information. However, if the visa validity period is insufficient for the program (although not any additional period), then you should contact the visa application centre through which you submitted.

Once you're in the UK, you may be eligible to [request an extension](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/extend-your-visa) although doing for tourism may not be approved. If you were issued a single-entry visa, you cannot change its validity period from within the UK.

Alternatively, you could make contact [UK Visas and Immigration](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk/y/outside-the-uk/english) help centre, a fee-based service:

> You can call or email English-speaking* staff with a question about your application.
>
> By phone
>   Telephone: 00 44 203 481 1736
>   Monday to Friday, 24 hours
>   Calls cost £1.37 per minute on top of your standard network charges.
>
> By email
>   [Email UK Visas and Immigration](https://contact-ukvi.homeoffice.gov.uk/app/international/payment/language/English). 
>   Emails enquiries cost £5.48. You will not be charged for any follow-up emails about the same enquiry.
>
> You’ll get a reply to your email within 2 days, except on Saturdays, Sundays and UK [public holidays](https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays).

*Service is [available in other languages.](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk/y/outside-the-uk?previous_response=english)